# iOS: Methods of ViewController subclass not visible in other classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, scope, subclass

I'm currently trying to develop an iPhone application.
Most things are working as I would expect and prefer.

Right now the issue I'm having is that when adding methods to one of my ViewControllers the methods are not visible from other parts of my applications.

When I add the same methods, with the same signature to my other view controllers they will be visible.

I've googled, browsed stackoverflow, reread, copy/pasted, and prayed to the spaghetti monster for divine insight, but to no avail.

There must be some minor detail, that I in my folly am overlooking. I hope you will be able to help me!

### InfoPageViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DB.h"

@interface InfoPageViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView* wv;
    DB* db;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView* wv;

-(void) reloadInfoPage;
@end
```

### InfoPageViewController.m

```
#import "InfoPageViewController.h"
@interface InfoPageViewController ()

@end


 @implementation InfoPageViewController
 @synthesize wv;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Information", @"Information");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabIcon-Settings"];
        db = [[DB alloc] init];

        // Custom initialization
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.    

   DBInfoPage* dbip = [db getInfopage];
   [wv loadHTMLString:dbip.html baseURL:nil];
   //NSLog(@"word%@", dbip.html);
   [self reloadInfoPage];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(void)reloadInfoPage
{
    DBInfoPage* dbip = [db getInfopage];
    [wv loadHTMLString:dbip.html baseURL:nil];
    NSLog(@"reloading infopage%@", @"");
}

@end
```

### infoviewtest.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InfoPageViewController.h"
@interface infoviewtest : NSObject

@end
```

### infoviewtest.m

```
#import "infoviewtest.h"

@implementation infoviewtest
-(void)test
{
    InfoPageViewController* ivc = [[InfoPageViewController alloc] init];
    [ivc reloadInfoPage];
}
@end
```

This yields an error of "No visible @interface for 'InfoPageViewController' declares the selector 'reloadInfoPage'.

I have also tried to use autocomplete to show me the available methods of the 'InfoPageViewController', this yields a list not containing 'reloadInfoPage', similarly the instance variable 'wv' is not visible from outside of the scope of the class.

I have tried closing and reopening xcode, as well as restart the computer.
I have also tried to 'clean' the project.

Any help will be greatly appreciated by the parts of my hair, not yet pulled in frustration.

If I have been lacking in providing information, please request and I'll do my best to respond.

Johan Abildskov

Comment: it may sound silly but have you tried closing xcode and reopening it again?

Comment: Not at all a silly question. I have tried closing xcode, reopening it again. I have tried rebooting the computer. I have tried building the project with clean target, to see if that did anything.

Comment: try to remove all the reference you have to DB.h, and post your result

Comment: it really looks like problem is in DB or somwhere further up in the #import chain

Comment: try to do the following move #import "DB.h" to InfoPageViewController.m, also in InfoPageViewController.h add @class DB; and see what happens, most likely if the error is in DB.h this will solve it temporarily

Comment: I have commented out all lines containing references to DB. Then build  clean, and rebuilt the project. This did not, unfortunately make any progress regarding the visiblity of my methods :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code look correct - all you have to do is probably clean the project and possibly restart XCode.

But you could optimize the linking/compiling by making some modifications like:

**infoviewtest.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//@class InfoPageViewController;  //add this if you'll be adding ivar or property of this type
@interface infoviewtest : NSObject

@end
```

**infoviewtest.m**

```
#import "infoviewtest.h"
#import "InfoPageViewController.h" //here's the place to import other headers

@implementation infoviewtest
-(void)test
{
    InfoPageViewController* ivc = [[InfoPageViewController alloc] init];
    [ivc reloadInfoPage];
}
@end
```

**EDIT:** Make sure that your implementation of **DB class** is correct. XCode error might lead you to wrong assumptions. Again: the code you've posted seems correct, just not optimized for compilation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll be moving my header imports into my .m files and use @class for properties and iVars, thank you for cleaning that part of for me. I use DB other places in my project and that implementation seems to me working correctly.

Comment: There's a possibility you've added some strange invisible characters with the editor. Check if the line-ends correspond to the end of text in each line. Also ditch the extra `@interface` in `InfoPageViewController.m` - seems like you don't need it.

Comment: Did you copy-paste this code from your XCode or were some parts typed in manually? I'm asking this because sometimes it happens that one `#imports` **.m** file instead of **.h** file by accident (XCode offers both):

Comment: Thanks, the extra interface is removed, I think it was automatically put there by xcode for some reason, but it does indeed seem redundant.
I've run through all line ends in InfoPageViewController.h and .m, no extra chars hidden :(

Comment: Code was copy-pasted. I believe in providing stuff verbatim for debugging. Very good point though!

Comment: Hmm, you really have a strange problem here. Something that's probably silly but can take hours to solve. Since this seems like a test project you could upload it somewhere so one could check it out. If it's not too far in the development stage yet, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a real project at work, I just created the infoviewtest class to be able to test InfoPageViewController in isolation.

Comment: O.k. hope you find the solution.

Comment: Thank you, will post if and when I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed an odd issue with test targets, when you don't include a class in the test target it still compiles, this could could be whats happening here so:

Have you included **InfoPageViewController** in your test target?

Comment: You are referring to whether InfoPageViewController is compiled and linked in the target? If so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect it seems. Even DB.h having the same method name, it will not affect the declaration of the same method in your controller class. Its quite strange error. Probably your XCode might get corrupted. Try to update Xcode and try the same code. If you are updating Xcode, update the iTunes too. This may fix your problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is suffering from this weird problem as I just did - the cause in my case was due to my ending up with 2 copies of the same class .m & .h files in different directories of my project after my Xcode newbie fumbling attempt to move them from one disk directory to another while keeping them in the same Xcode group. Xcode ended up allowing me to edit one set of files but used the other for compilation so the method that I added really didn't exist as far as the compiler was concerned, hence the above error message.